# ms-access + vb6: parameterized queries without stored queries

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, vb6, parameterized-query

I was wondering if in ms-access through vb6 (ADODB) i can have the security benefits of parameterized queries

```
    Set Prm = CmdEnn.CreateParameter("pText1", adBSTR, adParamInput)
    Prm.Value = pText1
    Cmd.Parameters.Append Prm
```

without using stored procedures. So having something like:

```
    Cmd.CommandText = "select * from ..."
    Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
```

instead of

```
    Cmd.CommandText = "stored_query_name"
    Cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
```

Comment: Have you tried? Where are you getting the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty, I deleted my answer

Comment: KekuSemau no it worked, seems that @pText1 inside the string does the trick.

Comment: With MS Access there are a number of things you can use as a parameter, ? is popular for example, what is important is the order in which the parameters occur.

Comment: @MirrorMirror: really? o.O I thought I had used that before, but now I got errors, looked around a bit and the webs say, OleDB providers do not support this kind of named parameters. How did you make this work?

Comment: @KekuSemau you can name the parameters, but they are not *named parameters*, the name only has a value as a mnemonic (param1, param2) which is the reason the order is all-important and possibly a reason why ? is popular. When named parameters are supported, the name refers to an actual entity and the order is unimportant.

Comment: ...hmm, I cannot use `@pText1` inside the `CommandText`... it says _must declare scalar variable @pText1_ . Wherever I look around, it says that _only_ the `?` works. _Does_ it work any way this an @ ? Maybe one of you two can post an answer with the code that works? (Kind of a funny thread now ;-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KekuSemau,

```
Cmd.CommandText = "select * from tablename where column like @pText1"
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Set Prm = CmdEnn.CreateParameter("pText1", adBSTR, adParamInput)
Prm.Value = random_variable
Cmd.Parameters.Append Prm
```

it worked like this, but in the end of the day, i didn't use it for other reasons. i don't recall if i had to use single quotes around it or not.